# /bin/sh Need to identify file content type

Tags: shell, file, sh, busybox

I'm working on busybox and have only /bin/sh available.
I would like to understand if the file I'm processing with my script are to be treated as ASCII (just read and do what I need to do) or gzip (so unzip first then do what I need to do).

The "file" command here would be perfect, but unfortunately it's just not available, hence I don't know what procedure to call as the input file I'm processing can be either format.

I'm wondering if there's a simple workaround I'm missing here to find this out...

Comment: What do you consider "non-ASCII"? Do you just need to test if your file has no characters with values outside 0-127?

Comment: You could check for the same magic number file looks for (IOW, make your own file that can only tell if a file is "gzip or not gzip")

Comment: BTW, whether `file` is available is completely orthogonal to whether you're using `/bin/sh` -- it's a command that's provided by your operating system, not your shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Just being curious - are you aware of an operating system which does NOT have `file` (maybe with exception of very old SCO Unix or SunOS or the like)? I'm surprised that the OP claims that `file` is not there.

Comment: @user1934428, I'm expecting it to be an embedded system. Lots of `buildroot`-style system-image-building tools have the availability of individual tools determined as separate toggles; I've certainly built ones without `file` (or `libmagic` altogether).

Answer (score 2):

Implicit in your question is that you *have* a `gunzip` command, and are trying to figure out whether you need to invoke it.

One command that can tell you that... is `gzip`.

```
contents_of_file() {
  local file="$1"
  if gzip -t <"$file" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    gunzip -c <"$file"
  else
    cat <"$file"
  fi
}
```

That said, you *can* also ask `grep` if a file has no non-printable, non-whitespace characters:

```
is_plain_text() {
  if grep -q -e '[^[:graph:][:space:]]' <"$1"; then
    echo "$1 has non-ASCII characters"
  else
    echo "$1 is plain text"
  fi
}
```